# How to define a variable to a public key in anchor?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, account

**I want to hardcode a public key in my anchor Solana program and then compare it with the public keys passed to the functions of the program.** Can someone please tell me how can I declare a variable which stores the hardcoded public key and then use it inside the function for comparing?

I get the following error while trying to use , I have defined tempkey inside the solana program

```
require_keys_eq!(ctx.accounts.user,tempkey);
```

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `!=` cannot be applied to type `anchor_lang::prelude::Signer<'_>`
  --> programs/solanatestdapp/src/lib.rs:19:9
   |
19 |         require_keys_eq!(ctx.accounts.user,tempkey);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----------------^-------^
   |                          |                 |
   |                          |                 anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey
   |                          anchor_lang::prelude::Signer<'_>
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `require_keys_eq` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> programs/solanatestdapp/src/lib.rs:19:26
   |
19 |         require_keys_eq!(ctx.accounts.user,tempkey);
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey`, found struct `anchor_lang::prelude::Signer`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use std::str::FromStr;

let key = Pubkey::from_str("CThXy1nb8YgSDjKpWRn4znasTbEdmXggJ9hoHEMdYfiQ").unwrap();
```

More about this trait: https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/pubkey/struct.Pubkey.html#method.from_str

Comment: And for comparison can I use "==" ?

Comment: There is ``require_keys_eq`` macro, use it to check if the keys are equal like this:
``require_keys_eq!(ctx.accounts.data.authority.key(), ctx.accounts.authority.key());``. More about this macro here: https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/macro.require_keys_eq.html

Comment: Yeah I was trying the same but I get the following error: 

AnchorError: AnchorError thrown in programs/solanatestdapp/src/lib.rs:19. Error Code: RequireKeysEqViolated. Error Number: 2502. Error Message: A require_keys_eq expression was violated.
Program log: Left:
Program log: 11111111111111111111111111111111
Program log: Right:
Program log: DAvvSoxKCxNKr8jTFYhDjiHW2EGojHnNcf6zt29sgYHd
    at AnchorError.parse

Comment: This is not an unexpected error. ``require_keys_eq`` is precisely doing its job. It is comparing the hardcoded key with the provided key and returning an error since they don't match. If you think this is mistake then problem most probably lies in the program logic. Can you paste the program's instruction and the client-side calling of the instruction in your original question?

Comment: Ohhh yes sorry, I was passing the wrong keys, now it is working but I have one more question , how can I use the public wallet key which was passed as context to solana program through JS function? Because I was passing it as accounts{user:provider.wallet.publickey } but when I try to compare it using require_keys_eq(ctx.accounts.user, temp_key) I get this error :

Comment: I will paste the error in the question

Comment: do I have to access the provided key through context in some other way?

Comment: Do like this: ``require_keys_eq(ctx.accounts.user.key(), temp_key)``.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143274/discussion-between-rounak-naik-and-0xshuk).

Answer (score 4):

Add `solana-program` to `Cargo.toml`

```
[dependencies]
solana-program = "*"
```

Add the following to `lib.rs`

```
use solana_program::{pubkey, pubkey::Pubkey};
```

Then you can hardcode pubkeys like this

```
pub const SOME_PUBKEY: Pubkey = pubkey!("E6W4RLUxZLQN5mjVfTAv7hTrdLR5Y6nrNvFiW8p1Q1m");
```

Then you can use the constant as a constraint to check against

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Example<'info> {
    ...
    #[account(
        mut,
        address = SOME_PUBKEY,
    )]
    pub example: Signer<'info>,
}
```

Comment: With Anchor it works too: `use anchor_lang::solana_program::pubkey`, but still I needed to add 'solana-program' to the dependencies, otherwise it gives `could not find 'solana_program' in the list of imported crates`, I wonder why?..